# adding new line to html body in mailcomposer

Tags: iphone, html, iphone-sdk-3.0, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How do i add a new line characters to html body of mail composer?

I have a string:

```
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><b>%%0D%%0AHello,%%0D%%0AHere's a link to your product%%0D%%0A<a href=\"%@\">click here</a>%%0D%%0A best regards</b></html>", currentProduct.url_product_details];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

When I set the body of a mail composer I see it without new lines.
How do i cause new lines to appear?

TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In HTML, newlines are `<br />`, not `%0D%0A`.

And use `<p>...</p>` for a paragraph.

For example,

```
NSString* emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"<html><head></head><body style='font-weight:bold;'>"
 @"<p>Hello,</p>"
 @"<p>Here's a link to your product<br /><a href='%@'>click here</a></p>"
 @"<p>Best Regards</p>"
 @"</body></html>", currentProduct.url_product_details];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! How do say that the text in my html doc should be right-aligned?

Comment: @Nava: `<p align="right">...</p>`. You can find more about HTML in http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp.